# Not getting output while using ImageMagick

Tags: android, imagemagick

I want to use ImageMagick library for image related stuff in my app.I have made sample code for it but after execution,it only shows the spinner and does not show the image obtained after processing.I don't know what is the problem?This is the code i am using:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.app_notes);


        try {
            final MagickImage img = new MagickImage(new ImageInfo("/sdcard/newsample.jpeg"));

//          setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

            ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,R.array.effects, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s.setAdapter(adapter);

            s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int pos, long id) {
                    ProgressThread t = new ProgressThread(img, pos);
                    //runOnUiThread(t);
                    t.run();
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // Do nothing.
                }
            });
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            iv.setImageBitmap(MagickBitmap.ToBitmap(img));
        } catch (MagickApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MagickException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
         * TextView tv = new TextView(this);
         * tv.setText(DisplayImageMetaData.displayMagickImage(img));
         * setContentView(tv);
         */
        int count = 2;
        MagickImage images[] = new MagickImage[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String path = "/mnt/sdcard/" + String.valueOf(i + 1) + ".jpeg";
            try {
                images[i] = new MagickImage(new ImageInfo(path));
            } catch (MagickException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            MagickImage image = new MagickImage(images);
            image.setImageFormat("gif");
            String fn = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/test.gif";
            image.setFileName(fn);
            ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(fn);
            info.setMagick("gif");
            //image.writeImage(info);
            byte blob[] = image.imageToBlob(info);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fn);
            fos.write(blob);
            fos.close();
            FileOutputStream testOS = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/test.txt");
            testOS.write("abc".getBytes());
            testOS.close();
        } catch (MagickException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        switch (id) {
        case PROGRESS_DIALOG:
            /*
             * ProgressDialog dialog =
             * ProgressDialog.show(AndroidMagickActivity.this, "",
             * "Loading. Please wait...", true);
             */
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            return progressDialog;
            // return dialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }


    /** Nested class that performs progress calculations (counting) */
    private class ProgressThread extends Thread {

        MagickImage img;
        int pos;

        ProgressThread(MagickImage image, int pos) {
            this.img = image;
            this.pos = pos;
        }

        public void run() {
            int effect = 0;
            MainActivity.this.showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            switch (pos) {
            case 1:
                effect = NoiseType.UndefinedNoise;
                break;
            case 2:
                effect = NoiseType.UniformNoise;
                break;
            case 3:
                effect = NoiseType.GaussianNoise;
                break;
            case 4:
                effect = NoiseType.MultiplicativeGaussianNoise;
                break;
            case 5:
                effect = NoiseType.ImpulseNoise;
                break;
            case 6:
                effect = NoiseType.LaplacianNoise;
                break;
            case 7:
                effect = NoiseType.PoissonNoise;
                break;
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                MagickImage image = null;
                if (pos < 8)
                    image = img.addNoiseImage(effect);
                else if (pos == 9)
                    image = img.blurImage(5, 1);
                else if (pos == 10)
                    image = img.charcoalImage(5, 1);
                else if (pos == 11)
                    image = img.edgeImage(0);
                if (image != null) {

                    bitmap = MagickBitmap.ToBitmap(image);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                MainActivity.this.dismissDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            } catch (MagickException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the log file:

```
09-25 22:45:13.322: V/Magick(554): Attempting to read from file /mnt/sdcard/1.jpeg
09-25 22:45:13.741: V/Magick(554): ReadImage completed
09-25 22:45:13.741: V/Magick(554): Attempting to read from file /mnt/sdcard/2.jpeg
09-25 22:45:14.112: V/Magick(554): ReadImage completed
09-25 22:45:14.534: D/dalvikvm(164): GC_EXPLICIT freed 151K, 7% free 21612K/23111K, paused 530ms+341ms
09-25 22:45:17.378: W/ActivityManager(80): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
09-25 22:45:18.417: W/ActivityManager(80): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{4117ad80 com.example.libmagick/.MainActivity}
09-25 22:45:23.281: I/ActivityManager(80): Process com.android.mms (pid 257) has died.
09-25 22:45:23.312: D/CountryDetectorService(80): No listener is left
09-25 22:45:30.272: D/dalvikvm(164): GC_EXPLICIT freed 57K, 7% free 21556K/23111K, paused 1035ms+723ms
09-25 22:45:34.442: D/dalvikvm(195): GC_EXPLICIT freed 112K, 5% free 12588K/13191K, paused 1724ms+88ms
09-25 22:45:41.332: D/dalvikvm(314): GC_EXPLICIT freed 158K, 5% free 12155K/12675K, paused 1287ms+291ms
09-25 22:45:59.741: V/TLINE(554): new: android.text.TextLine@40c43e30
09-25 22:46:00.462: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3165K, 22% free 14154K/17927K, paused 158ms
09-25 22:46:00.462: I/dalvikvm-heap(554): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.274MB for 1155904-byte allocation
09-25 22:46:00.662: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 15% free 15283K/17927K, paused 11ms+4ms
09-25 22:46:00.922: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 15% free 15282K/17927K, paused 71ms
09-25 22:46:00.952: I/dalvikvm-heap(554): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.232MB for 2054928-byte allocation
09-25 22:46:01.062: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 14% free 17288K/19975K, paused 95ms
09-25 22:46:01.262: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 14% free 17289K/19975K, paused 9ms+4ms
09-25 22:46:02.402: D/dalvikvm(164): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5K, 7% free 21551K/23111K, paused 5ms+129ms
09-25 22:46:06.522: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1286K, 18% free 16453K/19975K, paused 73ms
09-25 22:46:06.542: I/dalvikvm-heap(554): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.881MB for 1536016-byte allocation
09-25 22:46:06.722: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 17% free 17953K/21511K, paused 91ms
09-25 22:46:06.922: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 17% free 17953K/21511K, paused 7ms+4ms
09-25 22:46:07.212: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 17% free 17952K/21511K, paused 72ms
09-25 22:46:07.232: I/dalvikvm-heap(554): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.345MB for 1536016-byte allocation
09-25 22:46:07.422: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 16% free 19452K/23047K, paused 107ms
09-25 22:46:07.531: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 16% free 19452K/23047K, paused 97ms
09-25 22:46:07.552: I/dalvikvm-heap(554): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.810MB for 1536016-byte allocation
09-25 22:46:07.722: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 15% free 20952K/24583K, paused 138ms
09-25 22:46:08.781: I/ActivityManager(80): Displayed com.example.libmagick/.MainActivity: +1m1s413ms
09-25 22:46:08.781: W/InputManagerService(80): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@411f68b8
```